# What is a common practice when trying to do Inserts and Deletes with Entity Framework and Unit Of Work, all in the same commit?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I've implimented a Unit of Work pattern with my Entity Framework repository. ** *golf clap* **

Now i'm wondering what the common practice is, for doing multiple insets and/or deletes all within the same commit?

for example: Imagine I wish add 5 new objects/entities and for some reason, now delete entity #3.

```
// Arrange.
var uow = new UnitOfWork() { ... };
var myRepository = new MyRepository(uow);
var entity1 = new Entity(){ ... };
// ... snip snip ..

// Acts.
myRepository.Add(entity1);
myRepository.Add(entity2);
myRepository.Add(entity3);
myRepository.Add(entity4);
myRepository.Add(entity5);

 // do some logic ...

myRepository.Delete(entity3);

uow.Commit();
```

Will this work .. as in .. should the entities be added and THEN 1 removed from the db? Or will this only happen against the EF Entities list?

Is this bad practice? ie. never mix adds/updates with deletes? always commit before a delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's allowed, but the order isn't guaranteed. EF will try to figure out the best order, and throw if it can't. If this sounds hard to test comprehensively, well, you're probably right.

Comment: hi :) Can you update your answer to include how you would Arrange/Act/Assert the above test. eg. Create an object. Load it (so we know it was created). Then delete it and try to reload to see that it was deleted...

Comment: I wouldn't do this in a unit test at all since it could be provider specific. I'd do it in an integration test.

Comment: Ah soz. yeah. it's intergration testing, against the repo. how would u do that, though?

Comment: We do our integration testing with Selenium.